# Turn array values from a single dimension array into the depth of another array

Tags: php, arrays

So lets say I have the following array:

```
$value = 'x';

$foo = Array(
  0 => 'arraydepth1',
  1 => 'arraydepth2',
  2 => 'arraydepth3',
  3 => 'arraydepth4'
)
```

I need the values to be the keys, in order/depth, of the following array:

```
$bar['arraydepth1']['arraydepth2']['arraydepth3']['arraydepth4'] = 'x';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap you head around this:

```
function nest(Array $a, $lastValue) {
    $out = [];
    $ref =& $out;
    foreach ($a as $b) {
        $ref[$b] = [];
        $ref =& $ref[$b];
    }
    $ref = $lastValue;
    return $out;
}
var_dump(nest($foo, $value));
```

It is a little convoluted to explain, but here is my attempt:

- The `$out` variable is just an array that is going to be returned at the end of the function.
- `$ref` is a reference to the most recently nested array.
- In the loop we keep adding an array to the reference and then setting the reference to the added array.

Comment: You are not the hero that I need. You are the hero I deserve.